# How to increase the precision to get the correct roots at the boundaries?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, machine-precision

I want to solve an equation and Plot a graph of $\delta(\tau)$, where $0<\tau,\delta<1$. In principal $\delta(0)=1,\delta(1)=0$. However, when I solve the equation, the points near $\tau=1$ can't get exactly. Below is my sample code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
eps = 10^-13;
stepSize = 0.001; 
omegaD = 0.5; 
df = 0.008; 
c1 = omegaD/df; 
c0 = c0 /. FindRoot[1/c0 Log[Cosh[c1 c0]] == Sqrt[c1^2 + 1] - 1, {c0, Log[2]}];
list = Table[{τ, δ /. FindRoot[τ Log[Cosh[c0 Sqrt[c1^2 + \delta^2]/τ]/Cosh[c0 δ/τ]] == c0 (Sqrt[c1^2 + 1] - 1), 
                              {δ, 1}]}, {τ, eps, 1.0,stepSize}];
p1 = ListLinePlot[list]
```

Program complains that:

```
The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified \
by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient \
decrease in the merit function. You may need more than \
MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.@
```

Also clearly shown in the graph, the points near $\tau=1$ is missing.

[image]

So I tried to add an option `WorkingPrecision->30` at the end of the `FindRoot` function, the program complain the following this time:

```
the precision of the argument function ... is less than WorkingPrecision (30.)
```

Even I decrease 30 to other number, it still complaining.

**Question is how to add the missing points correctly at the boundary?**

Comment: The precision of your arguments must be at least as high as the `WorkingPrecision` you are requesting. You should change your parameters to exact values, e.g. `stepSize = 1/1000; omegaD = 1/2; df = 8/1000;` and retry.

Comment: As a sidenote to what @MarcoB correctly said, you can also just write `0.01//Rationalize` for instance. That might be more convenient for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `Table` does not run up to `t == 1.`:

```
Table[τ, {τ, 1/20, 1, stepSize}]
(*  {1.*10^-13, 0.001,..., 0.998, 0.999}  *)
```

**Update --**
Now with the corrected formula (a typo fixed in the OP), let's try

```
list = Table[{τ, δ /. 
    FindRoot[τ Log[Cosh[c0 Sqrt[c1^2 + δ^2]/τ]/Cosh[c0 δ/τ]] == c0 (Sqrt[c1^2 + 1] - 1),
     {δ, 1}]},
  {τ, Union[Range[eps, 1.0, stepSize], {1.}]}]
p1 = ListLinePlot[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We get the desired plot.

Comment: IF you do it analytically, you may find it is indeed 0. That is why I think I need more precision. I will show the analytical derivation when I am at computer.

Comment: It's my mistake, I wrongly typed a character in my code.

Comment: @buzhidao Thanks. I've updated the answer to your new input.

Comment: @downvoter, Why? It would be helpful to the site to indicate a reason you think there is an issue with the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I've also got that figure after I spot that misprint.